# Anyone know if there is a way to connect Neo4j to XSB Prolog?

Tags: neo4j

We do work in semantic reasoning.  Wondering if there is an existing way to connect Neo4j to XSB Prolog such that it can be queried. XSB supports loading data via MySQL and ODBC connectivity. Additionally we can load data from triple stores via an RDF file - however it's not exactly an easy task.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but a related question that might be worth perusing:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29192927/a-graph-db-vs-a-prolog-or-minikanren

Comment: In theory you should be able to use a ODBC-JDBC bridge and connect to Neo4j using JDBC - but I've never tried this approach.

Comment: @FrobberOfBits, yes not really related at all.  I know the differences; however we are actually using Flora-2 (which is a logic language built upon XSB Prolog).  I was considering the idea of using a graph db, such as Neo4J as the System of Record for our solution which has both standard CRUD operations and AI reasoning.